# How to hide action bar in Xamarin android and iPhone

Tags: web, xamarin, view

I want to know how to hide action bar in visual studio Xamarin android and iPhone?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more details for your question? Please show some related code.

Answer (score 1):

The styling you are trying to do with Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar is only for Android.

Use the following in the View of the page you want to perform cross platform action bar hiding for Android and iPhone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" >
...
</ContentPage>
```